# Is Powershell available for creating Azure Document Database account without using ARM Template?

Tags: powershell, azure, document-database

I am trying to create Azure Document Database Account using Powershell.

found a way to create it using ARM Template.

```
   ex: New-AzureResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location     
   $location -DeploymentName "Microsoft.DocumentDBWebSite" -Force -
   Verbose -TemplateFile .\DocumentDBJson\DocDBWebSite.json  -
   databaseAccountName $docDBAccountName -locationFromTemplate $location 
   -TemplateParameterFile .\DocumentDBJson\DocDBWebSite.param.dev.json
```

Is there any other way to create it using Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. DocumentDb can only be created using preview portal or ARM.

Here's the full list of Azure Powershell Cmdlets:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj554330.aspx